# Bar Graph - Compress/Shorten some elements

Tags: plotting

I have a bar graph that I'm plotting. Some of the values are very large when compared to others.
I want to put more focus on the smaller values, while still showing the larger elements.

The reason I want to do this is so that the resulting graph won't be unwieldy.

If I was drawing this by hand, I'd 'cut' the long bars and have a double-tilde in the middle of the element[image: graph example]

So my question is either:

1. Can this be done in Mathematica?
2. If not, can anyone think of a better way of keeping the dimensions of my graph small, while still containing enough detail to show the smaller values?

Comment: try Log your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {50, 715, 579, 5, 96, 295, 1100, 7, 117, 17, 22, 8, 7, 561};

Framed@BarChart[data,
  ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleRectangle",
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[data, Above]},
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> 500,
  Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

```
data = {50, 715, 579, 12, 96, 295, 1100, 430, 117, 17, 22, 8, 7, 561};

Framed@BarChart[data,
  BarOrigin -> Left,
  BarSpacing -> 0.3,
  ChartElementFunction ->
   ChartElementDataFunction["SegmentScaleRectangle", "Segments" -> 6, 
    "ColorScheme" -> "BeachColors"],
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[data, Right]},
  ImageSize -> 500,
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing",
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

Comment: `ScalingFunctions -> "Log"` is exactly what I needed.  It prevents me from `Log`ing my data in advance which is what I was kind of trying to avoid

Answer (score 3):

This is a rough work around. I am sure someone will come up with better idea.

```
 data = RandomSample[
       Join[RandomInteger[1000, 5], RandomInteger[10, 10]], 15];
    BarChart[data]
    Show[ListLogPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.0]], 
     BarChart[Log[data]]]
```

[image]

Comment: That is a nice workaround indeed, but I think @eldo 's solution is a bit more straightforward for my use!